# Is it possible to run hive on Spark in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I've been trying to develop a Spark program using the Apache Spark Framework.
I want to instantiate `HiveContext` without any clusters.
Is it possible to use `HiveContext` and run it locally via the Eclipse Scala IDE without using any cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply is it possible? Sure... (emphasis added)

> To use a `HiveContext`, *you do not need to have an existing Hive setup*, and all of the data sources available to a `SQLContext` are still available.

However, you need to compile some additional code.

> `HiveContext` is only packaged separately to avoid including all of Hive’s dependencies in the default Spark build. If these dependencies are *not a problem for your application* then using `HiveContext` is recommended

But, if you are just writing Spark without any cluster, there is nothing holding you to Spark 1.x, and you should instead be using Spark 2.x which has a `SparkSession` as the entrypoint for SQL-related things.

---

Eclipse IDE shouldn't matter. You could also use IntelliJ... or no IDE and `spark-submit` any JAR file containing some Spark code...

Comment: Thank you! i got a little confused because i'm just learning spark right now. What i wanted to know is to create and use a Hive table using the spark framework.

Comment: You would need a Hadoop cluster to create a Hive table, yes. Running Spark code itself does not require a cluster, no.